# Could you tell me why my program is not working?

Tags: c++

The task is to read string and swap the first char with the last. Here is my code: I don`t understand why is the imput the same as the output. Thanks very much for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter string: " << endl;
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    char first = str[0];
    int lastChar = str.length() -1;
    char last = str[lastChar];
    char temp;

    temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;

    cout << last << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (! str.empty()) std::swap(str.front(), str.back());`

Comment: You only output 1 character so I don't understand why the output is the same as the input for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not swapping the characters in the string but swapping the contents of `first` and `last` only. Then you only output the contents of `last` which is a single character. There are a couple of ways to approach this. One way is to swap the characters in the string directly like so.

```
char temp =  str[0];
str[0] = str[lastChar];
str[lastChar] = temp;
```

Alternatively you can also accomplish this with [`std::string::front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [`std::string::back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) if you are using C++11.

```
char temp = str.front();
str.front() = str.back();
str.back() = temp;
```

Another and more idiomatic and preferred way is to use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

```
std::swap(str[0], str[str.size() - 1])
```

Once you have finished your swap you can output the whole string with

```
cout << str << endl;
```

As a side note I recommend you do not use `using namespace std;` as it pulls the entire contents of `std` into the scope of the `using` statement. This can cause name collisions and other nasty side effects that can ruin your day.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the characters into the first and last variables and then swapping those rather than swapping the elements of the string.

```
temp = str[0];
str[0] = str[lastChar];
str[lastChar] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your only outputting 1 character as Neil Kirk said. how do you expect to get the whole string then?

Also `first` contains the last value of the string, and `last` contains the first value of the string, so try to incorporate those values with the problem and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
string str;      //string on which replacement would take place.
char temp;
int lastIndex = str.length() - 1;
temp = str[0];
str[0] = str[lastIndex];
str[lastIndex] = temp;
```